Grid.js with InertiaJS: Container is empty. Make sure you call render() before forceRender()
I'm trying to implement a Grid.js table in my Laravel, InertiaJS and ReactJS project, but I'm getting the following message:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Grid.js] [ERROR]: Container is empty. Make sure you call render() before forceRender()
Basically I have a component like this:
export default function MyComponent({ auth, institution, courses }: ComponentProps) {
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const grid = new Grid({
    sort: true,
    columns: ["Name", "Acciones"],
    data: courses.map((item) => [
      item.name,
      _(
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("click " + item.id);
          }}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      ),
    ]),
  });

  const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: "",
    date_start: "",
    date_end: "",
  });

  const submit: FormEventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    post(route, institution.id), {
      onFinish: () => {
        grid
          .updateConfig({
            data: courses.map((item) => [
              item.name,
              _(
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    console.log("click " + item.id);
                  }}>
                  Edit
                </Button>
              ),
            ]),
          })
          .forceRender();
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (wrapperRef.current != null) {
      grid.render(wrapperRef.current);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        { form }
      </form>

      <div ref={wrapperRef} />
    </>
  );
}

As you can see, my logic is the following:

Create a new Grid instance with the current columns and current courses object (provided by Laravel/InertiaJS)
I'm rendering the grid when the component renders for the first time using useEffect hook. Until here, everything works (the grid is displayed with the current courses).
When the form is submitted, I'm posting the data to the server, my controller saves the data and returns a redirect()->back(), then Laravel/InertiaJS rehydrates the compoment (updating the courses object).
Using the onFinished callback of the form post function, I'm passing a new configuration to Grid.js updateConfig method and a forceRender(). Here's where the error is shown. I'm using console.log(courses) to check if the object has the new element and it does, I mean, Laravel/InertiaJS is rehydrating the DOM correctly.

I've tried many different ways but I'm think this is the logic that should work. If there's another approach please let me know.
